# Simplifying expressions to $a+bi$ form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am asked the following question:

> Write $4e^{i\pi/4}$ in the form $a+bi$.

The answer that I got is $4[\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)]$. Is this correct?I am unsure if this is the simplest form in relation to the way the question asks for the answer to be written.

Comment: Hi! Use `$4[\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)]$` to get $4[\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)]$.

Comment: What is in the exponent of the exponential? Is it $e^{\pi i/4}$ or $e^{\pi/4}$?

Comment: @user85667 $e^{ipi/4}$

Comment: Yes, then your computation is correct. I guess you would distribute the $4$ too, to get $a=4\cos(\pi/4)$ and $b=4\sin(\pi/4)$. Perhaps also note that the values of sine and cosine for that argument can be expressed in terms of arithmetic operations, radicals, and rational numbers. You know, $\pi/4$ is the angle of an isosceles right-angled triangle.

Comment: To paraphrase Sean Connery's character in The Untouchables, you haven't gone all the way.

What is $\cos \frac {\pi} 4$?What is $\sin \frac {\pi} 4$? These are easy to simplify exactly, even if you have to use simple surds (square roots). Finally, why not distribute out the factor of $4$ on the outside? You want to get it looking like $a + bi$, which is simply a real plus another real times $i$. Nothing "fancy".

Comment: You haven't written it in a way that is in the form $a+bi.$ Bur you are almost there. You could also come up with the closed forms for the trigonometry values.