# Expressing $(6e^{i\pi/4}) \times(6e^{i\pi/4})$ from the exponential form to the form $a+bi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am given the following question in a course introducing me to the notion of complex numbers.

> Evaluate $(6e^{i\pi/4}) \times(6e^{i\pi/4})$ and express the resulting complex number in the form $a + bi$.

I am familiar with the $3$ forms complex numbers (exponential, trigonometric, real/imaginary decomposition) and would like to simplify the following problem and provide an answer with a complex number in a particular form that is different to the form of the complex numbers in the question:

I’m thinking I should use: $$e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$$ but I’m not quite sure. I can perform the multiplication without errors, but the problem is getting the answer in the correct form.

Using the above identity creates a situation where we have the product of multiple trigonometric functions and I am unsure how to simplify this in a suitable manner in line with the question.

I would love some help with this.

Comment: Yes, use Euler's formula. The best case scenario is if you can combine your exponentials together into a single power of $e$

Comment: You may either perform the multiplication in your polar form and then convert to rectangular form, or you may convert each $6e^{i\pi/4}$ to rectangular form (as in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4523874/89922)) then do the multiplication.

Comment: what would that look like if I combined them $6e^{ipi/4+ipi/4}$?

Comment: In the exponent, just add the two imaginary number $i\pi/4 +i \pi /4$. But don't forget to multiply the modulus $6$ too.

Comment: I’ve written a more explicit answer @fredflinstone

Answer (score 1):

First multiply and simplify:

$$\big(6e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\big) \times \big(6e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\big) = 36e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$$

You are correct that you can use $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$ to get an answer in the form that you want:

$$36e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}} =36\Big(\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)+i\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)\Big)$$

$$ = 36(0+i)=36i$$

Therefore, the answer is $36i$ (which is in the form $a+bi$ with $a=0$ and $b=36$ - as required).

---

*Note: this uses the fact that $\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)=0$ and $\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)=1$*

Answer (score -1):

You can multiply them:

$(6e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}) \cdot (6e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}) = 36i$ ; **USE**: $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}} = i$

Then, you can use $a+bi$ on the $36i$ is $0+36i$

By using Euler's Formula (mentioned in your question) it will be

$6(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})) \cdot 6(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})) = 0+36i$

Comment: how do you get 0+36i?

Comment: how can you assign $e^{ipi/2}$ like that?

Comment: I used $a+bi$ and a,b are real numbers, but we have $36 \cdot i = 36i$.

Comment: for your second question, I used the rule $e^{a} * e^{b} = e^{a+b}$

Comment: I understand the Euler implementation but I still dont understand where the 36i comes from