# Expressing $2e^{i\pi/2}+4e^{4i\pi/3}$ in $a+bi$ form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I am asked to express
$$2e^{i\pi/2}+4e^{4i\pi/3}$$ in the form $a + bi$.

If I use Euler's theorem, then $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i \sin(z)$

which gives me $$2e^{i\pi/2}+4e^{4i\pi/3}=2\cos(\pi/2)+i2\sin(\pi/2)
+4\cos(4\pi/3)+i4\sin(4\pi/3) \tag1$$

which simplifies to
$$0+2i-2-2i\sqrt3 \tag2$$

which simplifies to
$$-2+2i-2i\sqrt3 \tag3$$

Is this correct, or could this be further simplified?

Comment: Probably should factor out the I so that you have real+real*i

Comment: I was your curious did you mean to write last line with a positive 2 term or negative 2 term?

Comment: @BobbyOcean $2+i(2-\frac{2}{\sqrt3})$ is this what you mean?

Comment: @randomgirl I have made the necessary edit

Comment: Same user as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4523882/26369

Comment: Yes, that looks more like a+bi.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct so far. The last step is to factor out an $i$ to get:

$$-2 + (2 - 2 \sqrt3) i$$

in the form $a + bi$.