# Expression in the a+bi form

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked to express the $4e^{i\pi/4}$ in the form $a + bi$

if I use Euler's theorem, then $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i \sin(z)$

which gives me $4e^{i\pi/4}=4\cos(\pi/4)+i4\sin(\pi/4)$

Is this correct? or is it unfinished?

Comment: I think that’s it…

Comment: It is correct, but you should be able to simplify $\cos(\pi/4)$ and $\sin(\pi/4)$

Comment: @Fishbane simplify? They are both decimals so 2.82+i2.82

Comment: Expressing things as trig functions isn't a simple as they get.  Throw away you calculator and tell us what $\cos \frac \pi 4$ and $\sin \frac \pi 4$ *really* are (not as decimals nor as $\sin, \cos$ either).

Comment: To my mind $\sin \frac \pi 4$ is no more or less acceptable than, say, $7+(\ln \sqrt{e^{\sqrt{2}} }- 7)$.  After all there are an *infinite* number of ways to express the value and not all of them are useful.

Comment: @fleablood is this the correct simplification: $2\sqrt2$+i$2\sqrt2$

Comment: Same exact question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4523874/89922.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, this is right, but we can do better -- by simplifying the cosine and sine.

Now, you might recall that $\pi/4$ is a "special value" for your trig functions, and may even be able to recall it if you were tasked to memorize the special values on the unit circle (e.g. see page $3$ [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Trig_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)).

---

If not, you should at least be accustomed to the fact that $\pi/4$ is $45^\circ$ and hence be able to figure it out by hand.

Since sine and cosine operate on the unit circle, we'll draw a triangle with a $45^\circ$ acute angle and hypotenuse $1$. This immediately means that the other angle is $45^\circ$ and hence both legs are the same length $a$:

[image]

Well, we can find $a$ via the Pythagorean theorem:

$$a^2 + a^2 = 1^2 \implies 2a^2 = 1 \implies a = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

We can use, using the definitions of sine and cosine (in the sense of sine being "opposite over hypotenuse" and cosine being "adjacent over hypotenuse") that

$$\sin(45^\circ) = \cos(45^\circ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Then from here

$$4 \cos \left( \frac \pi 4 \right) + i \cdot 4 \sin \left( \frac \pi 4 \right)
= \frac{4}{\sqrt 2} + \frac{4}{\sqrt 2} i 
= 2 \sqrt 2 + 2 \sqrt 2 \, i$$

---

You can use this same idea to avoid memorizing the values for $\pi/3$ and $\pi/6$, as those come from the $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle.

[image]

And you can then even generalize this further to the entire unit circle, just by bearing in mind that $(x,y)$ on the unit circle translates to the point $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ for $\theta$ being the angle in question made, if you think about it all visually.

But I think I've made enough of a point with this. I just felt it all seemed to need elaboration since you defaulted to using decimals in the comments, so I assume you either haven't learned about the special values, or have since forgotten them.